# all possible combinations of a specific product in a query in PostgresSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a record of product combinations in Postgres database; these products can be sold separately or together. For example:

```
SELECT name, id_product, id_additional_product FROM product WHERE id = 1;
```

Result:

```
name | id_product | id_additional_product
x      1            -
x      1            2
x      1            4
```

Result, I need all possible combinations of a specific product, given a certain ID.:

```
name | id_product | id_additional_product | id_additional_product_1
x      1            -                       -
x      1            23                      -
x      1            46                      -
x      1            23                      46
y      23           -                       -
z      46           -                       -
...
```

Comment: It's good that you post sample data, but you should also explain what you want. I for one cannot understand it.